# What's meaning of the `d` and `t.` of the `drwxrwxrwt.` in linux?

Tags: permissions, ls

In the `/` directory, I use:

```
ls -alFd /tmp
```

to check the `/tmp` directory permissions and I get `drwxrwxrwt`.

I know `rwxrwxrw` means user, group, other permissions are read, write and execute.

But I don't know the meaning of the `d` and `t.` of the `drwxrwxrwt`, can someone explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The d letter means it's a directory (a folder if you prefer that name).
The t letter means that file is 'sticky'. Only the owner and root can delete a sticky file.

You may want to take a look at [this page](http://www.linuxnix.com/sticky-bit-set-linux/) if you want to know more about the sticky file permission.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions)

**Advanced Permissions**

The special permissions flag can be marked with any of the following:

- _ - no special permissions
- **d - directory**
- l - The file or directory is a symbolic link
- s - This indicated the setuid/setgid permissions. This is not set displayed in the special permission part of the permissions display, but is represented as a s in the read portion of the owner or group permissions.
- **t - This indicates the sticky bit permissions**. This is not set displayed in the special permission part of the permissions display, but is represented as a t in the executable portion of the all users permissions

Comment: I believe `s` is shown in the "executable" position.  There's also `S` (capital), which means setuid / setgid but without the corresponding execute permission.  Similarly there's `T` (capital), which means sticky without the corresponding execute permission.  Then there's `p`, which means "named pipe".